# Display Camera From Above?

Tags: opengl, jogl

I'm creating a bunch of rooms and need to display them from both first person (which I've covered) but also from above to show what's inside the rooms. The problem is that I can't figure out how to cut the roof off for the above view so it'll only display what's inside and not the roof/ceiling.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
    GL2  gl  = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // the "up" direction

    for ( int i=0; i<2; i++ ){
        //display first-person view here
        if(i == 0){
            gl.glViewport(0, 0, 600, 600);                  

            gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluPerspective(90., 1., .5, 100.);      

            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluLookAt(eyex, eyey, eyez,                 
                    eyex+Math.cos(Math.toRadians(viewangle)),   
                    eyey, 
                    eyez-Math.sin(Math.toRadians(viewangle)),   
                    0f,1f,0f);  

        }

        gl.glClear(GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        //display from above view here
        if(i == 1){
            gl.glViewport(600, 0, 600, 600);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluPerspective(90., 1., .5, 100.);      

            gl.glLoadIdentity();

            glu.gluLookAt(59, 90, 59.999,               
                    60, 0, 60,  
                    0f,1f,0f);  
        }

        room1.draw(gl);
        room2.draw(gl);
        room3.draw(gl);
        room4.draw(gl);
        room5.draw(gl);
        room6.draw(gl);
        room7.draw(gl);

        creature.draw(gl);
    }

    int error = gl.glGetError();
    if (error != GL.GL_NO_ERROR)
        System.out.println("OpenGL Error: " );
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but can't an object in a 3d scene have different opacity levels depending on what side you're viewing it from?

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding clipping planes (glClipPlane) to cut off the roof etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some engines makes variable distance from 3rd-person camera to player (camera moves closer to player if some obtacles are on the way). you can find the distance by reverse ray-picking (from player to max camera position).